# Construct Sforce.connection.query

Tags: custom-button, dynamic-soql

I have a query for a JS button:

`ccid = sforce.connection.query("Select Id, Account__c from CCI__C Where IsActive__c = True AND Account__c ='" +AccountId+ "'");`

It is working fine. Now I want to add `ORDER BY LastModifiedDate DESC LIMIT 1` to above query. I tried:

`ccid = sforce.connection.query("Select Id, Account__c from CCI__C Where IsActive__c = True AND Account__c ='" +AccountId+ "' + "ORDER BY LastModifiedDate DESC LIMIT 1"");`

But it gives an error when button is clicked:

> missing ) after argument list.

Can someone help me on this? Also it will be great, if a documentation/link can be provided for constructing these queries with the correct format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try like:

> ccid = sforce.connection.query("Select Id, Account__c from CCI__C
>   Where IsActive__c = True AND Account__c ='" +AccountId+ "'ORDER BY
>   LastModifiedDate DESC LIMIT 1");

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Is there any documentation/ link for reference?

Comment: @ManishAnand you can refer code sample here https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.ajax.meta/ajax/sforce_api_ajax_more_samples.htm